# Running `VBoxManage startvm ...`: how can I tell when the VM is running?

Tags: virtualbox

I tried using `VBoxManage guestproperty wait <vmname> ...` but what looked like obvious patterns didn't work.  I'm writing a script which imports a new VM, configures it, launches it, takes a snapshot, and then closes it, and obviously I need to know when the VM is running before taking the final two steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `showvminfo` output:

for Linux:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo "vm_name" | grep State
```

for Windows:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo "vm_name" | findstr State
```

See the thread below:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28611/how-to-automatically-start-and-shut-down-virtualbox-machines